# Firefox cannot connect to a local servers subdomain

Tags: laravel, firefox, laravel-5, safari

I'm working on laravel app ,i face issue with Firefox and Safari browser , when I need to access my web app with sub-domain for example `sub.localhost/myapp/public`  I see   **Server not found**
Whilst that opera and chrome working with me well

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 37):

**Best solution, supports multiple subdomains:**

1. Type in this url `about:config` search for
   `network.dns.localDomains`
2. double click the "value" field.
3. Enter your urls seperated by commas `www.localhost,app.localhost`

Comment: Searched for a solution for over 3 hours, this is exactly what I needed. The result is the same with `network.dns.native-is-localhost`, but without any of its issues.

Comment: A seemingly unnecessary restriction in FF that cost me (and probably others) hours of head-scratching. To save yourself having to re-edit this over and over again, you could opt for setting the value to `*.localhost` to cover all future cases.  Now all I have to do is remember this crazy exception the next I rebuild my machine!
*Correction*  don't use *.localhost -   I was lulled into a false sense of hope by the dns cache.   I'm leaving the comment here to help prevent others fall into my trap.

Answer (score 16):

The solution for me as of December 2016 on Firefox 50.0.2 is the `about:config` setting `network.dns.localDomains`:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Editing your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) might very well do the trick.

It probably already has entries right now. For instance, OSX has these by default:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Simply append the subdomains you need to it, for instance:

```
127.0.0.1     mysubdomain.localhost
```

The path to your host file on OSX is `/etc/hosts`, so `sudo nano /etc/hosts` to edit it, same for Linux.

---

Much credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38912011/5941620)

Comment: For some reason Firefox ignores the host file, but this does work for other browsers

Comment: It worked on my machine ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯
(OSX, firefox 66.0.3)

Comment: This worked for me although it is highly annoying to have to add subdomains to the hosts file. Chrome doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Visit `about:config` on your browser then search for `network.dns.native-is-localhost`

The default value is `false`. Toggle to `true` and you'll be good to go

Comment: WARNING: This makes your browser only access localhost. You wouldn't be able to use it for anything else. I had to refresh my browser and reinstall all my extension because i forgot what the settings name was. This is a terrible solution, no external scripts, images ect. would load on the page, no fonts, no CDN

Answer (score -1):

**setting 'network.dns.disableIPv6' to false (default is true) did the trick for me.(If you dont know how to set this then you can go to the bellow link)**

The following link may help you to resolve the problem for you. Try this.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can

Comment: Thanks for replay Praveen George but network.dns.disableIPv6  the default value is false ,please review your link .

Comment: This has nothing to do with subdomains

Answer (score -1):

If a problem arises like firefox can't find server so, it might be a networking problem. To fix it make sure that your modem/router are both not indicating errors:

1. make sure internet security software is not blocking connections to the internet
2. check address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com.