# How to test sub-domains on my localhost on a mac?

Tags: macos, dns, subdomain

I have set up a web application on I am running it on my localhost. That is - http://127.0.0.1:8000/. I have set up sub-domains as well. For example, going to http://blog.127.0.0.1:8000/ should take me to the blog part. However, my browser does not recognize this and says server cannot be found. My OS is MACOSx

> If you want to test subdomains on your local host, you need your browser to resolve multiple subdomains as '127.0.0.1'. The way you do this depends on your OS. If you're using linux, you would edit /etc/hosts.

I got this bit of info from another user, however, I have no idea how to do this on my Mac. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/hosts`, add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com blog.example.com
```

Then try http://example.com:8000/ and http://blog.example.com:8000/

Comment: Works like a charm! But the /etc/hosts file does have a comment that reads "Host Database

 localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
 when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry."
What could possibly go wrong by adding subdomains?

Comment: You should probably not remove existing `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry, but I don't see how adding additional hostnames could have any ill effect

Answer (score 12):

***Must be*** adding to the file `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost blog.localhost lvh.me blog.lvh.me
```

***Example for Vim editor*** (small overview about working in Vim)

1. Run to edit file `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
    sudo vi /etc/hosts
   ```
2. In Vim press on keyboard button <kbd>i</kbd> to switch on edit mode
3. Add this line:

   ```
    127.0.0.1       localhost blog.localhost lvh.me blog.lvh.me
   ```
4. Save file:

- Press button <kbd>Esc</kbd> and after press together buttons <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>
- Now you will see line in which write `x` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Thats all, `localhost`, `blog.localhost`, `lvh.me` and `blog.lvh.me` are already available for **all ports** that you are using.